# event for touches ended for a uibutton

Tags: iphone

I have a button which i drags using the code:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

is there any controlEvent that can be used as touches ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for: `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and/or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`

Answer (score 0):

Set BOTH touchUpInside and touchUpOutside events.

Check them out here:
[Control Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragExit)

Comment: Ahh, sorry, duplicate. dredful already answered it. I'll leave this up for the link, though.